# Copiar una variable entera a un array de caracteres

Tags: c

```
int main () {
    int numero = 23;
    char letra = 'z';
    char numeroYletra[20];
}
```

¿Cómo guardo la variable entera y el carácter en el array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes combinar [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) y [`strncat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/). Debes tener cuidado con `strncat` si hay posibilidad de provocar un desbordamiento de buffer, aunque con un poco de aritmética y `strlen` se puede solventar, teniendo cuidado de aplicar `strlen` siempre sobre un array con carácter nulo asignado o otro desbordamiento de buffer nos acecha...

En tu caso un `int` difícilmente va a llegar a almacenar un número de 18 dígitos..., lo comento como precaución general.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define BUFFER_SIZE 20

int main(){
    int numero = 23;
    char letra = 'z';
    char numeroYletra[BUFFER_SIZE] = "";

    snprintf(numeroYletra, BUFFER_SIZE, "%d", numero);
    strncat(numeroYletra, &letra, BUFFER_SIZE - strlen(numeroYletra) - 1);

    printf("%s", numeroYletra);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!